# Unable to read input using read.table but working fine with read.delim

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to read a tab separated file in R. The input file looks like

```
Display_Name    Card_Transaction_Id Amount  Description Transaction_Date    Type    Transaction_Category_Name   CustId


Axis Bank (India) - Credit Card 295704447   14.4200 Service Tax @ 15.00%    2016-11-03  debit   Service Charges/Fees    10491693

Axis Bank (India) - Credit Card 295704449   96.1300 EMI Interest - 9/24, Ref# XXXXXXX   2016-11-03  debit   Interest    10491693
```

when I am using read.table function it is unable to process the # in line 2 whereas `read.delim` is working fine, `read.table` gives blank values post # in line 2 whereas `read.delim` is giving me a proper response

I am writing both function which I am using, can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
x <- read.table("....",header=TRUE,sep="\t",skipNul=TRUE,fill=TRUE)
```

For read.delim I am giving the following inputs

```
x <- read.delim("....",header=TRUE,skipNul=TRUE)
```

Comment: Add `comment.char = ""` to your `read.table` parameters - otherwise it treats everything after # as a comment (to be ignored). This is already the default setting in `read.delim`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it is working :)